# how to get children transform position

Tags: unity-game-engine

Root Position:

[image: GameObjectRoot]

Child Position:

[image: Child]

Position Child I would like. (position obtained by changing the father:

[image: Right Child Position]

I'm trying to get the position of the child of a block.

More precisely as shown by the image I would like the position of the block shown in the inspector after setting the parent to `null`.

I tried with `transfrom.position`, but it doesn't work.

Does the inspector show the `transfrom.localPosition`?

when the `gameObject` has no parent the `transform.localPosition = transform.position`?

why can't i get that position by just doing a `transform.position`?

Comment: You can't see transform.position in the Inspector, it will always show transform.localPosition.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! If you don't use that language don't use that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Vector3 child_position = parent_gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).transform.position;
```

Comment: Did you mean `Vector3`? ;)